# sql server notifying running programs

Tags: c#, .net, sql, clr

I have a database which can be updated from several instances of a C# .NET program.
I wish to have each of those programs notified when rows in a table change.

An obvious (but possibly quite wrong) approach might be to register a callback function within the .NET program with the CLR Stored Trigger in the SQL Server, so that it gets called when the trigger fires.

Is this the correct/possible way, or is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to see SqlDependency with SignalR if you are using asp.net app http://bit.ly/VU3faT

Comment: Here's a nice article for you to read: [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get notifications.